# Getting DbEntityValidationException when trying to seed ApplicationUser to DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, code-first, identity

I'm getting a very persistent error trying to seed my DB using code first and Identity Users. I'm basically using the default `MVC ApplicationUser` and I've some classes that have an `ApplicationUser` as atribute (like a foreign key to an `ApplicationUser`). However, I keep getting a `DbEntityValidationException` telling me that I already have the user I'm trying to seed in the DB (yes, the database is dropped beforehand). What I guess is happening is that whenever I seed a class that has a `ApplicationUser` as attribute, it creates it again. Someone knows how to prevent this? The code I'm using:

Adding user:

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
var user = new ApplicationUser() {
  UserName = "User20",
  Email = "Email20@Example.com",
};
manager.Create(user, string.Format("Pricardo{0}.", i.ToString()));
```

Adding another type of class:

```
var tlu = new List<ThemeLevelUser> {
            new ThemeLevelUser { LevelID = levels[0], ThemeID = themes[0], UserID = user, Date = new DateTime(2015, 4, 1) },
            new ThemeLevelUser { LevelID = levels[0], ThemeID = themes[0], UserID = user, Date = new DateTime(2015, 4, 7) },
            new ThemeLevelUser { LevelID = levels[0], ThemeID = themes[0], UserID = user, Date = new DateTime(2015, 4, 12) }
          }
tlu.ForEach(x => TLURepository.Insert(x));
TLURepository.Save();
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

> new ThemeLevelUser { LevelID = levels[0], ThemeID = themes[0], UserID
>   = **user.ID**, Date = new DateTime(2015, 4, 12) }

with an .ID and not as a reference because it tries to create the whole 'user' upon insert as a child entity. Just the ID and you will have no problems. You can do this by adding two separate properties - ThemeLevelUser.User and ThemeLevelUser.UserId - EF will recognize by convention that the latter is the foreign key to the former. Then you set just the ThemeLevelUser.UserId and you are done with the foreign key constrains without the error.

Comment: Do I need to change the atribute in the other classes too?

Comment: If they have the Id of the user as a foreign key constraint - yes.